# How I can do Google search, using Grab

Tags: python

Good morning!
I learn Python and library Grab.
I want search in Google using Grab. I have this code

```
from grab import Grab
g = Grab()
g.go('https://www.google.com.ua/')
g.doc.set_input("q","grab")
g.doc.submit()
print g.doc.select('//head/title').text()

print g.doc.select('//h3[@class="r"]/a')
```

And the result of this code is it:

```
Grab - python фреймворк для парсинга сайтов
<selection.selector_list.SelectorList object at 0x022F9E90>
```

First 'print' must write "grab - Пошук Google", isn`t it? But it displays the result, which must write second 'print'.
Why is this happening?

Comment: It would be very great if you consider using the common english example and show us what you expect. Otherwise people here have to try and translate things. :)

Comment: g.doc.select('//h3[@class="r"]/a') isn't a string... so it causes an error when you try to print...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send form with `g.doc.submit()` Grab submits it with automatically chosen  `I'm Feeling Lucky` button.

If you want to receive actual results of Google search you have to specify submit button

```
In [50]: g.go('https://www.google.com.ua/')
Out[50]: <grab.document.Document at 0x7f2552014050>

In [51]: g.doc.set_input("q","grab")

In [52]: g.doc.submit(submit_name = 'btnK')
Out[52]: <grab.document.Document at 0x7f2552014170>

In [53]: g.doc.select('//head/title').text()
Out[53]: u'grab - \u041f\u043e\u0448\u0443\u043a Google'

In [54]: print g.doc.select('//head/title').text()
grab - Пошук Google
```

`g.doc.select('//h3[@class="r"]/a')` returns a list of all elements, that matched your xpath expression.

```
In [59]: for el in g.doc.select('//h3[@class="r"]/a'):
   ....:     print el.text()
   ....:
Grab - python фреймворк для парсинга сайтов
Grab — Викиучебник
Grab | Define Grab at Dictionary.com
Grab — Вікіпедія
grab - Англо-русский словарь на WordReference.com
Grab — python библиотека для парсинга сайтов ...
grab - definition of grab by The Free Dictionary
lorien/grab · GitHub
grab 0.6.5 : Python Package Index
```

If you need only the first result you can use

```
g.doc.select('//h3[@class="r"]/a')[0]
```